# How to get all term descriptions from a specific taxonomy vocabulary?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have a block that displays an imagemap, and each map area represents a taxonomy term. All terms are in the same vocabulary.

For each map area, I know the term name and want to pull the term description using a Drupal function. I know I can do something like this:

```
<?php $myTerm = taxonomy_get_term_by_name('1'); ?>
<area shape="poly" title="<?php echo $myTerm[0]->description; ?>" coords="1,2,3" href="link2" />
```

But it's quite clunky and means making a function call for every map area.

Is there an API function that gets every term in a vocabulary (like taxonomy_node_get_terms_by_vocabulary() but without referencing a node?)...

Or should I make a module for this..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use [taxonomy_get_tree](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_tree/6) or just write your own query_function with the following query: `db_query('SELECT description FROM {term_data} where vid = %s',$vid)`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't an API function for that. You can get the terms with an EntityFieldQuery, and you can wrap it in a function for convenience:

```
function taxonomy_term_get_by_vid($vid) {
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $result = $query
  ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'taxonomy_term')
  ->propertyCondition('vid', (int) $vid, '=')
  ->execute();
  return $result['taxonomy_term'];
}
```