# Get whole tree of a taxonomy term from node into seperate php variables

Tags: taxonomy-terms

Can anyone of you brainy folk suggest the best way of retrieving the taxonomy term on a node and both of it's parents then storing as variables on a php snippet?
For example: Country->City->District output to $country, $city and $district?

Thanks in advance for all your answers!...

nb, this is what I get from print_r, [0] being the country, [1] being the area and [2] the district:

```
field_location_term] => Array
    (
        [und] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [tid] => 26
                        [taxonomy_term] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [tid] => 26
                                [vid] => 5
                                [name] => B----a
                                [description] => 
                                [format] => filtered_html
                                [weight] => 3
                                [vocabulary_machine_name] => geographical_location
                                [metatags] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [tid] => 27
                        [taxonomy_term] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [tid] => 27
                                [vid] => 5
                                [name] => B----o
                                [description] => 
                                [format] => filtered_html
                                [weight] => 0
                                [vocabulary_machine_name] => geographical_location
                                [metatags] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [tid] => 28
                        [taxonomy_term] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [tid] => 28
                                [vid] => 5
                                [name] => M----w
                                [description] => 
                                [format] => filtered_html
                                [weight] => 0
                                [vocabulary_machine_name] => geographical_location
                                [metatags] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )
```

I thought the best thing to do would be

```
$country = $node->field_location_term['und'][0]['taxonomy_term']['name'];
```

But I get no output.

Comment: Check this question: [Get all term from tax vocab](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3142/how-to-get-all-term-descriptions-from-a-specific-taxonomy-vocabulary?rq=1)

Comment: Isn't it always the way; I've been researching this one solidly for the past 3 days, just after I post the reply I find out my way works but I was entering it incorrectly, it should have been: `$country = $node->field_location_term['und'][0]['taxonomy_term']->name; ` - DOH!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears from your printout that taxonomy_term is an object, not an array. So your code would look like this:

```
$country = $node->field_location_term['und'][0]['taxonomy_term']->name;
```

You might not be able to do the object->['array']->object->['key'] thing. It might need to be broken into:

```
$foo = $node->field_location_term['und'][0]['taxonomy_term'];
$country = $foo->name;
```

Comment: Thanks Beth, i think i must have been replying to myself when you answered the post - looks like great minds think alike : )